# Point Charge placed above an infinite dielectric slab

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

> Find the force on a point charge $q$ placed a distance $d$ above the XY plane with the region $z<0$ filled with dielectric with susceptibilty $\chi_{e}$.
> (From Griffiths EM, Example 4.8)

The author employs two methods, one which calculates the $z$ -component of the net electric field at a point $\mathbf{r}$ from origin in the XY plane and then use it in the relation $\sigma_{b} = P_z = \chi_e \epsilon_0E_z$ to find $\sigma_b$. The other one uses the familiar Image Method, both of which makes perfect sense. The surface charge density comes out to be:

$$\sigma_b = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\chi_e}{\chi_e+2}\frac{qd}{(r^2+d^2)^{3/2}}$$

However, I tried to do it on my own with the use of Displacement Vector D. Here's how I proceed:
$$\oint_{\mathcal{S}}\mathbf{D\cdot}d\mathbf{a} = Q_{f\,encl}$$

where $\mathcal{S}$ is the gaussian surface, a sphere centered at $q$ with radius $\mathcal{R}$, therefore

$$D\cdot(4\pi\mathcal{R}^2) = q$$ $$\text{or}\;\;\mathbf{D} = \frac{q\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}}{4\pi\mathcal{R}^2}\;,\;\;\text{everywhere}$$

$$\text{so,}\;\;\mathbf{E}=\frac{\mathbf{D}}{(1+\chi_e)\epsilon_0}=\frac{q\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\epsilon_0\mathcal{R}^2}$$

$$\therefore\;\;\mathbf{P}=\chi_e\epsilon_0\mathbf{E}=\frac{\chi_eq\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\mathcal{R}^2}\;\;\text{, just below the surface, inside the dielectric}$$

Now, $\sigma_b$ will be then just $\mathbf{P\cdot\hat{n}}$, where $\mathbf{\hat{n}=\hat{k}}$ and $\mathbf{\mathcal{R}=r-}d\mathbf{\hat{k}}$. So,

$$\sigma_b = \frac{\chi_eq\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}\cdot\hat{k}}}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\mathcal{R}^2} = - \frac{\chi_eqd}{4\pi(1+\chi_e)\mathcal{R}^{3}}\;\;\text{as,}\;\mathbf{\hat{\mathcal{R}}\cdot\hat{k}} = - \frac{d}{\mathcal{R}}$$

$$\text{i.e.,}\;\;\;\sigma_b = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{\chi_e}{1+\chi_e}\frac{qd}{\mathcal{R}^{3}}$$

which comes out to be different from the one found above, surely something has gone wrong, but I am not able to make out what am I missing here.

**Although I have used the correct equations but it seems that they do not apply nicely in this case, for which I am unsure of why the displacement method does't work here, what difference does it causes from the above two methods.** Is it ok @ACuriousMind?

Comment: I just literally spent more than two hours of latex formatting to ask the question, which does not demand for checking my work, just why the usage of different equations didn't work here, can you please reconsider it @ACuriousMind

Comment: I am not interested in which methods works or which doesn't,  I am interested in WHY the method of using displacement gives a wrong result, that's all

Comment: Your question asks along the lines of "What am I doing wrong?" which is typical of homework-like and check-my-work questions. Phrasing your question as such makes it extremely prone to closure.

Comment: Hi Aditya.  You say that this question doesn't demand checking your work, but it certainly *does*, because a correct analysis using the $\mathbf D$ field *does* yield the correct answer.  As a result, your question reduces to "please go through my work and find the place where I made a mistake."  To make the question more on-topic, you might consider focusing on the steps where you may have made a conceptual error. Since the tangential component of $\mathbf D$ is discontinuous across an interface, I would suggest starting with your assumption of spherical symmetry.